# Does Android delete cache files on external storage?

Tags: android, caching

The Android documentation [states](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#InternalCache) that files in the cache directory of **internal** storage can be deleted when the device is low in internal storage space.

Is there ever a case when files in the cache directory of **external** storage are deleted? For example from this directory:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packageName/cache/...
```